# Angular Login Component Redirect if User is Already logged

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular5, angular6

This is my router guard for my angular project. Basically in my system i have many user roles. In the guard i check on the userProfile node if the user isLawyer and isLawyerApproved. If these conditions are true, the lawyer can access to the route. in the canActivate function i return this.loggedin && this.isApproved. In my login component i have a ngOnit function that checks if the user is already logged and if is, redirects to the /dashboard route. Actually, that does not working, I want that if an authenticated user visits the login page, automatically be redirected to the /dashboard. Please help me

```
class MyGuardService implements CanActivate{
  loggedIn = false;
  isApproved:boolean;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router){
    this.authService.isLogged().subscribe((response)=>{
      if(response && response.uid){
        this.loggedIn = true;
        this.authService.getUserProfile(response.uid).valueChanges()
          .subscribe(
             (userProfile:UserProfile)=>{
                if(userProfile.isLawyer && userProfile.isLawyerApproved){
                   this.isApproved = true;
                }
             }
           )
        }else{
          this.loggedIn = false
        }
      }, (error)=>{
      this.loggedIn = false;
    })
  }

  canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    console.log('El abogado es aprobado??')
    console.log(this.isApproved)
    if(!this.loggedIn){
      this.router.navigate(['/abogado-login']);
    }
    return (this.loggedIn && this.isApproved)
  }
}
```

// LoginComponent

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.authService.isLogged().subscribe((result)=>{
    if(result && result.uid){
      console.log('Estoy logueado debo redirigir');
      this.router.navigate(['/abogado'])
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your gaurd just add redirection by improting router on success of login true or what ever your condition and place that gaurd on login route in router module.

```
constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router){
  this.authService.isLogged().subscribe((response)=>{
  if(response && response.uid){
  this.loggedIn = true;

  this.authService.getUserProfile(response.uid).valueChanges()
  .subscribe(
   (userProfile:UserProfile)=>{
    if(userProfile.isLawyer && userProfile.isLawyerApproved){
     this.isApproved = true;
     this.router.navigate(['/addroutewhereusershouldgowhenapproved']);
    } else {
     this.router.navigate(['/abogado']);
   }
  )
}else{
 this.loggedIn = false
}
}, (error)=>{
 this.loggedIn = false;
})
```

In router module add gaurd on route path something similar below.

```
{ path:'', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer solved my problem.